# SQLAlchemy and Elixir?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-elixir

I have been using django ORM, it's nice and very easy, but this time I'm doing a desktop app and I found SQLAlchemy, but I'm not sure to use it with Elixir. What do you think? is it really useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use SQLAlchemy with Elixir if you need Django-style (or Rails-style) simple object-relational mapping. If you need complex mapping like [concrete table inheritance](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/mappers.html#concrete-table-inheritance) or [dictionary-based collections](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/mappers.html#dictionary-based-collections), I recommend you to use just SQLAlchemy with [`sqlalchemy.ext.declarative`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/declarative.html).

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure you need Elixir any more. With the [Declarative mapper](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/ext/declarative.html), you can create classes that map to your tables similar to the way it's done by Elixir. Is there a specific elixir feature that you're looking for?

Comment: are there any interesting feature that i would like to use?, Declarive mapper is even more clear to read and write, thanks.

Comment: It's been too long since I've used either library so I can't say for sure.